# How to display to total number of tests run, failed, skipped using the streamlineReporter in Detox

Tags: detox

I've recently upgraded to the new `streamlineReporter` in Detox: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Jest.md

Is there a way to display the total number of tests Passed, Failed, and Skipped after the tests have completed like it used to be displayed in jest?

This is what it looks like now:

[View after multiple tests have completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATDgG.png)